# ui-router 0.2.10 returns Error 404 for nested views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I am kinda at an impasse right now. I did the [thinkster.io tutorial](https://thinkster.io/topics/mean) about the MEAN Stack and they use [angular ui-router](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/) in order to handle states and routes.

They make use of **inline templates** which are really handy in a small application. However I desire to use partial templates outside of the main `index.ejs` (I am using Express view engine with .ejs). My problem is that the `$stateProvider` does not seem to be able to find my `home.ejs` file in order to inject it in the `<ui-view/>` of `index.ejs`. I have been poking around GitHub and StackOverflow since yesterday but did not find a solution that would work for me.

Here is the organization of my files so far, most of the folders being generated thanks to the **Express generator** (only the relevant ones are included):

```
--public
----javascript
------angularApp.js (contains factories, controllers and configuration)
--routes
----index.js (uses the express router)
--views
----home.ejs
----index.ejs
----posts.ejs
--app.js (initialization file)
```

In `app.js` the view engine is defined as follow:

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Thus the path towards the **view** folder should be properly defined (and with the help of some `console.log()` it seems it is. Here is the code part in `angularApp.js`:

```
app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      // template: '<h1>This Is A State</h1>' ,
      templateUrl: '/home',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      resolve: {
        postPromise: ['posts', function(posts) {
            return posts.getAll();
        }]
      }
    });
}]);
```

Concerning the **templateUrl** I tried different versions depending on what I found (`/home.ejs, home.ejs, /views/home.ejs, /views/home, ../../views/home.ejs, ../../views/home, etc...`) but none seemed to solve my problem. I might be completely missing something obvious but I cannot point it out.

This is my `index.ejs`file (minus the `html` and `head` tags as well as the `script` ones):

```
  <body ng-app="appName">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default pull-right" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!-- Navbar definition -->
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h1 class="md-display-3"><a href="/#/home"> AppTitle </a></h1>
        </div>
        <ui-view>Hm. There should be something here.</ui-view>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Needless to say, the *Hm. There should be something here.* is properly displayed!

I read a few post about partial templates requiring some kind of `index.home` format and the ex-inline templates would become `parent.child.html` or something like that but I haven't tried it yet because I would like to not change the name of my files (although it is probably better with a bigger application) yet.

Thanks in advance, and don't hesitate to point me towards a post I might have missed.